# pylint: disabling R0921 does not work, still warning

Tags: python, pylint

I have a class which has two methods that raise `NotImplementedError` and also inherits from an abstract class (a class that contains abstract methods, from the `abc` package. This parent class in turn inherits from a class marked as abstract through `__metaclass__ = ABCMeta`). Due to this a R0921 warning is raised when running pylint on my code. If I remove the `NotImplementedErrors` pylint does not give that warning. Now, I've tried disabling the R0921 for the class like this:

```
# pylint: disable=R0921
class Wrapper(AbstractWrapper):
    ...
    def func(self, kwargs**):
        raise NotImplementedError
    ...
```

But it does not seem to work. I still get the warning "Abstract class not referenced". What am I missing?

Comment: Huum, this sounds like a bug. Please submit a ticket on http://www.logilab.org/project/pylint. Thanks

Comment: @sthenault: I can only see already created, active tickets under the Tickets page. Do I need to register? Or must I email someone?

Comment: created a ticket for you: http://www.logilab.org/ticket/111138

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a bug and has been reported, see the ticket at the pylint tracker  http://www.logilab.org/ticket/111138